# How to linearize the multiplication by a binary decision variable?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, linearization, pulp

I am currently optimizing a hydrogen production chain.
I am optimizing the production regime, and the size of the required wind, solar and the electrolyser.

For every hour of the year, the production level of the electrolyser should be lower than the sum of the production of wind and solar and higher than 10% of the electrolyser capacity, if the sum of wind and solar is below 10% of the electrolyser capacity, I want the production level to be 0. I have the production pattern for a 1 MW unit for both wind and solar, noted by $W_t, S_t$ for every timestep t. The sizes of the electrolyser, solar and wind are noted as $X_e, X_s, X_w$. The total energy required in a year is $E_r$. The production level for every hour is $p_t$.

Now I know that in non-linear programming, using a variable $u_t$ can be used to 'turn off' the electrolyser, but you would have to multiply it by the size of the electrolyser $X_e$, making the constraint non-linear. I have read somethings about the big-M method, but I have difficulties formulating this exact problem into that method. Could somebody please help me?

Below, I have tried to express in symbols what I mean.

$ \sum p_t = E_r$

$W_t X_w+S_t X_s - p_t \ge 0$ for all t

$p_t -X_e \le 0$ for all t

**if** $W_t X_w+S_t X_s \ge 0.1 X_e$

$p_t -0.1 X_e \ge 0$

**elseif** $W_t X_w+S_t X_s < 0.1 X_e$

$p_t = 0$

I am working with the PuLP package in Python.

Comment: what are the variables, and also what type? also please, clarify the indices of the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that your variables are $X_{w}$, $X_{s}$, $X_{e}$, and $p_{t}$. Then as @RobPratt suggested, we can use two separate disjuncts.

$$ W_t X_w+S_t X_s - 0.1 X_e \geq m(1-z_t) \quad (1)$$
$$ p_t -0.1 X_e \geq m(1-z_t) \quad (2)$$

......

$$ W_t X_w+S_t X_s - 0.1 X_e \leq M z_t \quad (3)$$
$$ p_t \leq M z_t \quad (4)$$
$$ p_t \geq m z_t \quad (5)$$

If the auxiliary binary variable $z_t$ is equal to one, the first two constraints, (1,2), are activated, and if $z_t$ is equal to zero, the second third constraints, (3,4,5), would be activated.

Comment: $p_t$ is also a variable.  For your contrapositive, the $\le$ should instead be $<$. But a simpler idea is to enforce four implications, where $z_t=1$ enforces two and $z_t=0$ enforces the other two.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, thanks. I just added a comment to clarify the model specification. also I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you A.Omidi for your quick response. And yes @RobPratt, that's true. I am working with a data-set with a wind and solar yield for every hour of the year. So the variables are $X_w,X_s,X_e,p_1,....,p_(8760)$. I don't completely understand what you mean by enforcing four implications. Could yo maybe write that out in constraint form?

Comment: @KlaasR, thanks. are $w, s, e$ indices? also what does $760$ mean?

Comment: $X_w$ is the amount of MW installed Wind capacity, $X_s$ is the amount of MW installed Solar capacity, $X_e$ is the amount of MW installed Electrolyser capacity. The 760 was a mistake, it is the 8760th variable of $p_t$.

Comment: I assume the only index is $t$. Is it true?

Comment: I am not completely at home in this field. But i believe so yes, There are a total of 8763 variables, the three sizes $X_w,X_s,X_e$ and the 8760 variables $p_t$.

Comment: @RobPratt, as I tested with the different models by at least CPLEX and SCIP, I do not see any complaints with keeping $\epsilon$ in the formulation or NOT. In all of the cases, the results are the same. May I have your insight about this?

Comment: Thank you for all the help @A.Omidi. I have one more question, what is the difference between the M and the m?

Comment: The parameters $M$ and $m$ are actually the upper and lower bound of mentioned constraints. You should take them carefully based on your problem data.

Comment: So that would be for instance M = +1 million and m = - 1 million?

Comment: @KlaasR, it heavily depends on your problem data. You have to check that.

Comment: If $p_t$ is not near the breakpoint, the small $\epsilon$ won't matter.  I suspect the bounds on $p_t$ are $[0,E_r]$, in which case you don't need (5).  The $m$ values for (1) and (2) are different, and the $M$ values for (3) and (4) are different.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, thanks so much. 

Comment: I have no upper bound on $p_t$ because the objective function should take care of minimizing p_t. 
Could you maybe help me point the way in determining the value of $M$? I thought that it should be a number that is on a different scale than the decision variables and constraints. The constraints are at maximum around 5000, so I picked for M 10^20. But it doesn't seem to work, as I am still encountering $p_t$ values between 0 and $0.1X_e$.